# Parse String (stdobject) in file to stdobject

Tags: php, file, object

I'm trying to parse a `stdobject` written in a file to a `stdobject` that I can use to code with.

These are the lines in the file.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [result] => 
    [NumberDocument] => 3
    [Error] => 1
    [Errors] => stdClass Object
)
```

// This code is run to get the result above

```
ob_start();
include_once("file.txt");    
$result = ob_get_contents();    
ob_end_clean();    
pr($result);    
die();
```

Comment: Please share us the code you have added.

Comment: Why would you have that in a file in the first place? You're going to find it difficult parsing that, why not use serialize / unserialize?

Comment: This is a soap response writen to a file.

Comment: SOAP responses are XML, so nope

Comment: It's writen from the xml file to a file

Comment: What is generating this SOAP response? What is giving you what looks like a print_r of an object instead of a serialization that can already be read?

Comment: not a good approach, the soap response should be converted into an array and you should serialize it before saving, get the serialized value and reserialise it.

Comment: `It's writen from the xml file to a file` better save xml and get the data from on application level

Comment: You can't do anything with that, write it to the file with `json_encode`.

Comment: I thought it would be a simple function call to parse the file to a object or array :). Thank you for the advise people.